# How do I iterate through all directories within a parent directory to get the hash of all files, then step back to go through remaining directories?

Tags: python, iteration

I am building a file integrity monitor in Python. My current challenge is figuring out how I might iterate through all directories that are present in a user-selected parent directory in order to verify the hashes of all files present, and then save the hashes to a txt file called baseline.txt. Once a directory has been fully scanned and there are no more directories within the current sub-directory, I want to go back up one automatically and scan the next directory and then do it again until there are really no more directories under that parent directory and all the files have been scanned. Here is my code:

```
def new_baseline():
    # Calculate hash from the target files and store in baseline.txt

    if os.path.exists(baseline):
        os.remove(baseline)
    # For each directory within the chosen directory
    # scan each file
    # then move onto the next directory and scan each file there until there are no more deeper directories
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filehash = hashlib.sha256()
            fn = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
                while True:
                    data = f.read()
                    if not data:
                        break
                    if data:
                        filehash.update(data)
                f.close()
            f = open(baseline, 'a')
            print(f"{fn} | {filehash.hexdigest()}", file=f) # Sends the print output to the baseline file
            print(f"{fn} | {filehash.hexdigest()}")

            f.close()
```

**directory** is the dir that the user has selected in the main function. This function works if it's only one directory I am scanning but, refer to my issue above. How may I iterate through all files within a directory then go down again, then come back up to look at a different directory?

These are the directories directly under my documents dir, which is the chosen dir i want to scan.

[image]

This is the test files dir

[image]

This is the hp dir

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the scope of this go down / go up thing. If `direcctory` is the parent directory, are you saying you want to go to _its_ parent? `os.walk` will get all of the subdirectories under the parent.

Comment: `fn = os.path.join(directory, filename)` isn't right. You want `fn = os.path.join(subdir, filename)`. Is that your problem?

Comment: @tdelaney wow that actually did work, thank you! It really is the simplest detail I don't see.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is in building the full path name to the files. `os.walk` iterates the parent's directories only. It yields the directory it is currently looking at plus the subdirectories and files you'll find in it. Use `subdir` to build paths to the files contained.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        filehash = hashlib.sha256()
        fn = os.path.join(directory, filename)
```